# Does BCS support creating an external list from an existing list in a different web application using List Web Services

Tags: bcs, external-content-type, bdc-model, external-list

I have sharepoint 2010 farm where there are multiple web applications. I am trying to understand BCS and its capabilities. This is the structure I have :-

Web Application A > Site Collection  > Custom List (i)

Web Application B > Site Collection  > {need an external list here that refers to the Custom List (i).

A farm administrator account has full control rights on both the Site Collections. I wanted to know if it possible to create an External List in Web App B using BDC from the Internal List in Web App A.

I tried connecting to the list web service(lists.asmx) through SharePoint designer to create an external content type.I am able to connect to the list web service of the Web App A but I am not sure if I can create "Operations" on the returned methods by the web service.

Can someone guide me here a little.